# Show Non-US holidays in the KDE Digital Clock calendar view

Tags: kde, plasma5, calendar

I recently moved to a different country and want to see the national holidays in the KDE calendar that shows when you click the clock (the Digital Clock 3 in the taskbar). However, the KDE cal only shows US holidays and I cannot find a way in the config and on the web to change that.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the gear symbol near the top right of your screenshot to open the settings window of the KDE clock widget (which is responsible for the calendar display).

Then select "Holidays" from the left column, and pick the country or countries you want.

Comment: Great, this looks like the right place. However, when I selected new holidays (and unselected the old ones) nothing changed. Do I need to restart KDE/Linux?

Comment: It required indeed a restart to apply the change.